# Proving that $\sum_ {n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}} $ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

> Prove that the following series converges:
>
> $$\sum_ {n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}} $$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} = 0$$
So, the alternating series converges.

Is it right to my procedure?

Comment: Well, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\lt \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, but that happens to be what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use [Alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) for series $\sum(-1)^n a_n$ you should have

1. $a_n\geq 0$
2. $a_n\geq a_{n+1}$
3. $\lim a_n = 0$

In your approach you wrote that $a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}>\frac{1}{\sqrt n} = a_{n}$ which is wrong and not what you need. Fix it and your solution will be correct.