# Checking if series converge: $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(1+i)^k}{k!}$ etc.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I want to see if these series converge:

$$\text{1.  }\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}$$
$$\text{2.  }\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(1+i)^k}{k!}$$
$$\text{3.  }\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^2+2}{k^4+1}$$
$$\text{4.  }\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^2 +2}{k^3+1}$$

Regarding $1.$ I used the alternating series test and got $a_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$. The limit is $\lim_{k \to \infty} a_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} = 0$. So I have to show that $$a_k \geq a_{k+1}$$ $$\Leftrightarrow \frac{1\sqrt{k+1}}{\sqrt{k}} \geq 1$$ $$\Leftrightarrow \frac{\sqrt{k+1}}{\sqrt{k}} \geq 1$$ which is true.

Regarding $2.$ I used the ratio test which would give

$$|\frac{a_k+1}{k!}| = \frac{\frac{(1+i)^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}}{\frac{(1+i)^k}{k!}} = \frac{(1+i)^{k+1}\cdot k!}{(k+1)! \cdot (1+i)^k} = \frac{(1+i)^{k+1} \cdot k!}{k! (k+1) \cdot (1+i)^k} = \frac{(1+i)^{k+1}}{(k+1)\cdot (1+i)^k}$$, but where do I go from here?

Regarding $3.$ I used the ratio test as well and got

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} |\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}| = \frac{\frac{(k+1)^2+2}{(k+1)^4+1}}{\frac{(k^2+2)}{(k+1)^4+1}} = \frac{((k+1)^2+2) \cdot ((k+1)^4+1)}{((k+1)^4+1) \cdot (k^2 +2)} = \frac{(k+1)^2+2}{k^2+2} = \frac{k^2+2k+3}{k^2+2} = \frac{k^2 \cdot (\frac{2k}{k} + \frac{3}{k^2})}{k^2 \cdot \frac{2}{k}} = 2$$

Regarding $4.$ I just rewrote it as

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{k^2 \cdot \frac{2}{k^2}}{k^3 \cdot \frac{1}{k^3}} = 0$$

Can someone please help me? (I just started learning about sequences)

Comment: You should avoid asking 4 questions at once like that. You might also want to check previous questions on the site with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/), I would be surprised if none of these has ever been asked before.

Comment: 3. should be $1$, use comparison test with $\frac{1}{n^2}$

Comment: Case in point : [here's the first](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151041/proving-that-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1n-sqrtn-converges).

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Where did you get the $\frac{k+3}{k^2}$ from?

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thanks and yes, but one can only ask 1 question every 40 minutes and it made sense to put them together here since they're all about convergence and more or less similar

Comment: If there is a restriction on the number of questions you can ask, you're supposed to respect it and wait before asking more, not try to go around it.

Comment: regarding 2 ... $$\frac{(1+i)^{k+1}}{(1+i)^k} = 1+i$$  If you frequently miss things like this, then maybe you need to go back and work on algebra a bit more.

Comment: @GEdgar That gives $(1+i) \cdot \frac{1}{k+1}$. So the limit is $0$?

Comment: yes you have it now.

Comment: @TaylorLeibnitz Regarding 2. you can compute the actual sum. In general,

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^k}{k!} = e^z -1$$

In this case the sum is $e^{i+1}- 1  = e (\cos 1 + i \sin 1) -1 $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. What you did is fine.
2. The absolute value of a complex number is always real and non-negative. So you have 
   $$
   \left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right|= \left|\frac{(1+i)^{k+1}}{(k+1)(1+i)^k}  \right|
   =\left|\frac{(1+i)}{k+1}\right|=\frac{|1+i|}{k+1}=\frac{\sqrt2}{k+1}.
   $$
3. Your limit is wrong. It's $1$, which gives you no information. Here you would usually do comparison. Something like 
   \begin{align}
   \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{k^2+2}{k^4+1}
   &\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{k^2+2}{k^4}
   =\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{k^4}<\infty.
   \end{align}
4. Here you also want to do comparison. The terms are basically $1/k$, so you want should expect this to diverge. You can do
   $$
   \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{k^2+2}{k^3+1}\geq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{k^2}{k^2+k^3}=\frac12\,\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1k=\infty.
   $$

===========================

If you are weak with inequalities, you can do the comparison in 3 and 4 by taking limits instead. Namely, if the number $a_n$ and $b_n$ are positive and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\tfrac{a_n}{b_n}$ exists and is not zero, then $\sum_na_n$ converges if and only if $\sum_nb_n$ converges. So in 3,
$$
\frac{\frac{k^2+2}{k^4+1}}{\frac1{k^2}}=\frac{k^2(k^2+2)}{k^4+1}=\frac{1+2/k^2}{1+1/k^4}\to1
$$
tells you that the series behaves like $\sum_k\frac1{k^2}$. And in 4 you can do 
$$
\frac{\frac{k^2+2}{k^3+1}}{\frac1k}=\frac{k(k^2+2)}{k^3+1}=\frac{1+2/k^2}{1+1/k^3}\to1.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Can you tell me what went wrong with my $3.$ and $4.$?

Comment: In 3 you tried to use the ratio test. But the limit is 1, which gives you no information; I don't know what you did to say that the limit was 2. In 4, I'm not sure what you tried to do (probably some products there are actually sums), so I don't know what conclusion you expected to get from that limit.

Comment: I included mention on how to do 3 and 4 without dealing with inequalities but dealing with limits instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate it! Regarding $2$. How do you know that $|1+i| = \sqrt{2}$?

Comment: By definition of absolute value: $$|1+i|^2=(1+i)\overline{(1+i)}=(1+i)(1-i)=2.$$

Comment: Ah I see. And regarding $3.$ How did you choose that the denominator is $\frac{1}{k^2}$?

Comment: Because $\frac{k^2+2}{k^4+1}$ is basically $\frac1{k^2}$.